# Send Web Push Notifications from Spring Boot to Angular app using ServiceWorker and Firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, spring-boot, push-notification, web-push

Ok the title is hopefully clear.

So I'm having problem of sending `web push notification` to Angular app. I think it's some kind of configuration problem. I managed to register `ServiceWorker` within my web app but I don't now how to tell to Spring to send the notification to one particular browser instance (via `FCM`).

Here are the steps that I did:

1. Create Angular app (Using Angular 12)
2. Added `ServiceWorker` with `ng add @angular/pwa`
3. With `web-push generate-vapid-keys --json` I generated keys:

`{"publicKey":"BGtAaq5M386BKsp5fm-3veucVeedsO5ah0kEhGyCV_Q9LEe82cKcpayKU3Owe1z1KE-vT9_ATFZ-G2HEjjHoGtM", "privateKey":"cX6cCdC-ZX6fhI9ff9EeZ5ch6bnXx1x6jwOZxmPLmt8" }`

4. Managed to register `ServiceWorker` and get `subscription` object
5. Here are is my Angular component and how `ServiceWorker` "looks like":

   export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

   ```
      readonly VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY = "BGtAaq5M386BKsp5fm-3veucVeedsO5ah0kEhGyCV_Q9LEe82cKcpayKU3Owe1z1KE-vT9_ATFZ-G2HEjjHoGtM";

      constructor(private swPush: SwPush) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.swPush.messages.subscribe(data => console.log(data))
      }

      subscribeToNotifications() {

        this.swPush.requestSubscription({
            serverPublicKey: this.VAPID_PUBLIC_KEY
        })
        .then(sub => {console.log("Notification Subscription priiiint: ", sub); })
        .catch(err => console.error("Could not subscribe to notifications", err));

      }

    }
   ```

[image: Subscription object]

6. I created Project and App on Firebase by following this [tutorial](https://golb.hplar.ch/2018/01/Sending-Web-push-messages-from-Spring-Boot-to-Browsers.html). And I do have code in my Spring application which is able to send messages/notifications (name it how you want) to Firebase. But I don't know how to tell FCM (via Spring) to send message to browser instance which subscription object I console-logged (that is `PushSubscription` object from the image above).

What I have seen in other tutorials is that instead of console-logging `PushSubscription` object, they send (usual POST request) it to `NodeJs` server which has `web-push module`. And the use it to send messages to actual notification to specific browser instance. The code goes something like this:

```
     export function sendNotif(req, res) {
    
         const webpush = require('web-push');
    
        // sample notification payload
        const notificationPayload = {
            "notification": {
                "title": "Angular News",
                "body": "Newsletter Available!",
                "icon": "assets/main-page-logo-small-hat.png",
                "vibrate": [100, 50, 100],
                "data": {
                    "dateOfArrival": Date.now(),
                    "primaryKey": 1
                },
                "actions": [{
                    "action": "explore",
                    "title": "Go to the site"
                }]
            }
        };
    Promise.all(USER_SUBSCRIPTIONS_ARRAY.map(sub => webpush.sendNotification(
        sub, JSON.stringify(notificationPayload) )))
        .then(() => res.status(200).json({message: 'Newsletter sent successfully.'}))
        .catch(err => {
            console.error("Error sending notification, reason: ", err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
        });

}
```

7. I did not that in tutorial above they are importing some firebase script on client side. But they are not using public key generated in step 3.

Does anyone know how to configure this?

Comment: U've got the message and thats the good part that ur workis done, now for each user who access ur pwa, u should generate him uuid and store it in ur dB, and after that in ur backend, u do ur notification crud... send for single user or array of specific users by their uuids, send for segments, send for groups... and prepare ur notification from backend side... and from the frontend, u send http request the notification crud u've done with params u need, if request was on send to users, u send array of uuids as parameter, and maybe title/image/etc...

Comment: And in the this.swPush.messages.subscribe((data:any) => {// u need to create a notification component and append it to the document with the data}

Comment: Well, storing uuids as you say is not a problem, can be a temporary data structure. As I sad, I don't know what to pass to my backend (from frontend, after I got PushSubscription) so Firebase can send msg/notif to that one particular user...

Comment: U have to send nothing after u get push subscription, now all ur work is in this.swPush.messages.subscribe.... is to receive the messages from backend and preview them to the user.... in case u need to send notifications from frontend to others, then u need to use httpClient.. this.http.post('url to crud I mentioned above", { title: "", ids: [uuids I mentioned above],etc}, {headers: {auth headers of ur server}}).subscribe... and like this u send request server to send notification to specific user so ur server sends notification to users and they receive it with this popish.messages subscribe.

Comment: @MostafaHarb Thanks for the answer, but I'm new to this..I don't really get what you want to say. How will generating uuid (which some kind of random number) help me (i.e. firebase) to send notifications? I'm pretty much sure that value of 'endpoint' in PushSubscription object is unique for each browser instance

Comment: @MostafaHarb Please, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68769331/unable-to-receive-notification-in-angular-app-from-firebase-console