# Unable to receive notification in Angular app from Firebase Console?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire

Ok, I've tried many things, read all the posts from SO (which are usually from 2018 or 2020 and are using Angular 8, 9 or 10).

I'm using Angular and FCM to receive notifications/messages. For now, these steps I managed to do:

1. Create Angular app (Using Angular 12)
2. Install following dependency, with command: `npm install @angual/fire firebase`. According to this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5rDd4_-dMFo&list=PL8NTBhIXP2gHG95OHjwWtlIUvEhRRXo9F&index=7), which is great btw, the author says that command will install two dependencies which will establish communication between Angular project and Firebase. So here is what I got in my `pacakage.json` (omitted for brevity, couldn't upload as JSON, bad formmating by SO):

[image]

Pay attention on `@angular/fire`, `@angular/core`, `firebase` and `@angular/service-worker`.

```
4. Added new file called `firebase-messaging-sw.js`:
    
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.9.1/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
firebase.initializeApp({
    // REPLACE BY YOUR FIREBASE CONFIG HERE
    apiKey: "some data",
    authDomain: "webpush-some data",
    projectId: "webpush-65d56",
    storageBucket: "webpush-65d56.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "some data",
    appId: "1:703095985397:web:some data",
    measurementId: "G-NBDLKT8P0L"
});

// Retrieve an instance of Firebase Messaging so that it can handle background
// messages.
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
     
5. `app.module.ts`:

    //other imports
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';
    import { environment } from '../environments/environment.prod';
    import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
    import { AngularFireMessagingModule } from '@angular/fire/messaging';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
        AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
        AngularFireMessagingModule,
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }

6. In angular.json file in asset array:

     "assets": [
                  "src/favicon.ico",
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/manifest.webmanifest",
                  "src/firebase-messaging-sw.js"
                ],


  7. In both environment.ts files:
     
     export const environment = {
  production: false,
  firebaseConfig: {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyAukoKAGsome data",
    authDomain: "some data-asf.some data.com",
    projectId: "asf-65d56",
    storageBucket: "asf-d.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "some data",
    appId: "1:asd:web:some data",
    measurementId: "G-NBDLKT8P0L"
  }
};

And finally, `in app.component.ts`:

    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{


   constructor(updates: SwUpdate, 
               private swPush: SwPush, 
               private firebase : FirebaseApp, 
               private  afMessaging: AngularFireMessaging) {
 

  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.requestPermission()
    this.listen();
  }

  requestPermission() {
    this.afMessaging.requestToken
    .subscribe(
      (token) => { 
        console.log('Permission granted! Save to the server!', token);
        // TODO: send token to server
       },
      (error) => { console.error(error); },  
    );
  }

  listen() {
     this.afMessaging.messages
       .subscribe((message: any) => { 
         console.log(message);
         //THIS WON'T WORK !!!
    });
  }
```

The good thing is that from `requestPermision()` I am able to get the token (unique browser identifier) and use it on `FCM Console` and send actual notification. The bad thing is that I cannot make `listen()` method to work, that is, it wont print in the console any data, BUT notification from the browser (I think `ServiceWorker` is responsible) is displayed with title and body what I passed from the `FCM Console`.

What else I have tried to place in `listen()` method?

```
**Attempt 1.**

    const messaging = firebasee.default.messaging();
    messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      // If we want to display 
      // a msg when the app is in foreground
      console.log(payload);
  });

**Attempt 2.**

 this.afMessaging.onMessage.bind(this.afMessaging);
  this.afMessaging.messages
      .subscribe((message: any) => { 
        console.log(message);
        
        })
      });


 **Attempt 3.**
    //Note that this.firebase is from AngularFire, check in the constructor
      this.firebase.messaging().onMessage((payload) => {
    console.log(payload) 
  }, e => {
    console.log(e)
  })
```

After any change in the code, I build the project in following way:

```
1. ng build
2. http-server -p 8082 -c-1 dist/PushDemo
```

**Does anyone know which version or in what way I can make the notification event logged into the console?**

P.S. With all those version and dependencies the man can go nuts..

Comment: first u need to build ur app as production (ng build --prod) since service won't work in normal project build.. its a must to be a production build... second u need to launch the output project which is output in project/dist to a server... this server could be a local php location.. (example if u have xamp, u could place the folder in the dist inside xamp/htdocs/your project) and then u can test ur code by accessing localhost/ur project or localhost:specific port/ur project...  then after that after launching the page.. your should be able to see allow notfication msg and data should be there

Comment: When I type: ng build --prod, there is a message on the console saying ng build is equal to ng build --prod. I'm using a http-server ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server ) and starting my project from dist folder as you described with 2nd command: http-server -p 8082 -c-1 dist/PushDemo P.S. -c-1 means no cash.

Comment: aha so when u open the app it asks to allow notification?

Comment: No, the requestPermission() uses requestToken method (that is method from @angular/fire library; have a look at https://cutt.ly/xQZONiU and find explanation of requestToken, just read 'Shortcutting token requests' section in readme). Essentially,  requestToken allows notifications for you and gives you the token. It is like you have clicked 'Allow' on the popup. If I understood correctly.

Comment: https://arjenbrandenburgh.medium.com/angulars-pwa-swpush-and-swupdate-15a7e5c154ac

Comment: chek this link, i think u mostly odone everything, but try to do the notfication part from the application service workers push notfical panel... that what i mean of did u get notfication or not.... that is a test from ur side to see if ur code is 100% correct... then tell me the result so i can tell u the next part which is firebase base cloud messaging..

Comment: @MostafaHarb Will let you know what I did as soon as I find time to test again. Thank you Mostafa.